# Why is pressure in Calligraphic Brush inactive in illustrator while using wacom tablet?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, brush, drawing-tablet, wacom

Why is pressure in Calligraphic Brush inactive in illustrator while using wacom tablet?
[image]

Comment: Depends on wacom tablet

Comment: You have an issue with the Wacom Driver or the application preferences. If you have a tablet connected, pressure should be available there. Voting to close as "tech support".

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 types of callighraphic pen nibs: with wide and narrow nibs.  In case of narrow nib you apply pressure as you write:
https://www.jetpens.com/blog/calligraphy-pen-basics/pt/689

Anyway, if you tablet supports pressure pen, pressure option should be able in case of calligraphic brushes, check you tablet settings.
https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/how-to/illustrator-create-calligraphic-brush.html

This is my screenshot, Ilustrator cs6 and wacom tablet:  [image]